# How do we loop through the data frame based on column and retrieve the rows based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Question 2:Kindly bear with me as I am learning and trying understand Pandas with implementation

Lets say My data frame as below

`Date               A      B-Id   C            D   E
November 05, 2019  1      aa     article-12   23  34
November 07, 2019  1      aa     article-21   23  34
November 09, 2019  1      aa     sr.confirm   23  34
November 14, 2019  1      bb     article-30   23  34
December 14, 2019  1      bb     article-76   23  34
December 14, 2019  1      bb     article-04   23  34
December 15, 2019  1      bb     article-11   23  34
December 15, 2019  1      bb     sr.confirm   23  34
December 15, 2019  1      cc     article-54   23  34
December 16, 2019  1      cc     article-12   23  34
December 17, 2019  1      cc     article-12   23  34`

As per @Osbark the solution you have given will filter out the rows containing the string article and sr.confirm in C colum for each unique visitor_id i.e, B-Id.

As per the solution we get

`Date               A      B-Id   C            D   E
November 05, 2019  1      aa     article-12   23  34
November 07, 2019  1      aa     article-21   23  34
November 09, 2019  1      aa     sr.confirm   23  34
November 14, 2019  1      bb     article-30   23  34
December 14, 2019  1      bb     article-76   23  34
December 14, 2019  1      bb     article-04   23  34
December 15, 2019  1      bb     article-11   23  34
December 15, 2019  1      bb     sr.confirm   23  34`
Now I want further filter based on the date, return only the rows with sr.confirm and articles that are viewed on same date or 1 date prior
So I get
`
Date               A      B-Id   C            D   E
December 14, 2019  1      bb     article-76   23  34
December 14, 2019  1      bb     article-04   23  34
December 15, 2019  1      bb     article-11   23  34

### December 15, 2019  1      bb     sr.confirm   23  34`

Question1
Lets say I have a csv file as follows:

```
A   B   C            D   E
1   aa  articlle-12  23  34
2   aa  web service  22  35
3   aa               25  41
4   bb  article-23   12  21
5   bb  sr.confirm   34  23
6   bb  mobile       56  98
7   cc  sr.confirm   76  65
8   cc  new          97  51
```

In the above csv file, B- is the unique visitor_id.

What I want to do is take each visitor_id i.e, B, For ex: first visitor_id aa there are two rows then check for the condition if c has rows containing article string and another rw=ow containing sr.confirm string.

My final output csv file should be lik:

```
A   B   C            D   E
4   bb  article-23   12  21
5   bb  sr.confirm   34  23
```

I tried using pandas for the same and belwo is the code

```
import pandas as pd
# df = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/kb1.csv', index_col= "Page Name (custom) (evar31)" )
df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/KB123.csv')# print(df1)

df2 = df1[df1['Page Name (custom) (evar31)'].str.contains("my : group : get-support : file_SR : confirmation", na=False)]# print(df2)
# print(df2.keys())

df3 = df1[df1['Page Name (custom) (evar31)'].str.contains("kb : s : article : ", na=False)]# print(df3)
# print(df3.keys())
df4 = pd.merge(df3, df2, how='inner', on='Visitor_ID')
df4.drop_duplicates(subset="Visitor_ID", keep=False, inplace=False)
def drop_y(df): 
# list comprehension of the cols that end with '_y' 
to_drop = [x for x in df if x.endswith('_y')] 
df.drop(to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
drop_y(df4)

def rename_x(df):
for col in df:
if col.endswith('_x'):
df.rename(columns={col: col.rstrip('_x')}, inplace=True)

rename_x(df4)

df5 = df4.drop_duplicates(subset='Page Name (custom) (evar31)',keep='first', inplace=False)
df6 = pd.concat([df5, df2])df6.sort_values('Visitor_ID', axis=0, ascending=True,inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
print(df6['Page Name (custom) (evar31)'])
df6.to_csv(r'/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/new.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with a custom function, that filters out the visitors who don't have both `article` and `sr.confirm`, and only keeps these rows:

```py
def contains_string(group):
    mask_article = group["C"].str.contains("article")
    mask_confirm = group["C"].str.contains("sr.confirm")
    if mask_article.any() & mask_confirm.any():
        return group[mask_article | mask_confirm]
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame([])

result = df.groupby("B", as_index=False).apply(contains_string)
print(result)
```

```
     A   B           C     D     E
3  4.0  bb  article-23  12.0  21.0
4  5.0  bb  sr.confirm  34.0  23.0
```

Comment: Yes the above one works, Now I have a additional query which I have added in the top of the initial question, It would be great if you can help me how I can acheive that

Comment: Could you help me with the above query which has additional requirement

Comment: please ask a new question for additional queries

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using boolean logic masks with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) where `|` is logical `OR` and `&` is logical `AND`:

```
mask1 = df['C'].eq('sr.confirm')
mask2 = df['C'].str.contains('article')
mask3 = mask1.groupby(df['B']).transform('any') & mask2.groupby(df['B']).transform('any')

df[(mask1 | mask2) & mask3]
```

[out]

```
   A   B           C   D     E
3  4  bb  article-23  12  21.0
4  5  bb  sr.confirm  34  23.0
```